# I changed the dataset architecture and suddenly I have no valid results anymore

Tags: c#, sql

This is in relation to a previous question that I asked and was answered. To give a quick explanation, I have 3 different projects using the same datasource and so they told me to create a n-tier architecture for my projects which I did. I have the following code that used to work and doesn't anymore after the changes. I inserted a breakpoint and the tables are still getting filled with the proper info but amexQuery returns no results. I'm sorry for sounding so clueless but I don't know what in the world would be causing this.

EDIT: I believe the source of the problem is the library reference because I inserted a breakpoint at the amexQuery and it is immediately timing out and giving me the default error of Function evaluation disabled because a previous function evaluation timed out.

```
dailyAmexAdapter.FillBySymbol(dailyAmexTable, symbol);
dailyAmexAdapter.FillBySymbol(dailyGlobalTable, symbol);

                    var amexQuery = from c in dailyGlobalTable.AsEnumerable()
                                    where c.Date >= DateTime.Now.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromDays(30))
                                    orderby c.Date descending
                                    join d in dailyAmexTable.AsEnumerable() on c.Date equals d.Date
                                    select new { date = c.Date, stockClose = d.AdjustedClose, sandpClose = c.AdjustedClose };

                    if (amexQuery.Count() > 0)
                    {
                      // do something
                    }
```

Comment: can we see some data of the tables? so we can understand what you expect

Comment: what does this method look like `FillBySymbol` make sure that before you assign the datasource that you set it to null first since you are using the same datasource

Comment: I'm sorry if I wasn't clear but this code hasn't been changed from before and it did work as it was supposed to. The table is still being filled with the same data as before but after changing the datasource to a class library reference, it no longer works

Comment: ID Symbol Open High Low Close Volume AdjustedClose Date
7 ADDN 0.75 0.75 0.75 0.75 0 0.75 2000-04-25

Sorry I copied this from a row in the table

Comment: The FillBySymbol is a method created using the dataset designer so it is automatically created

Comment: start by simplifying.  make a much simpler query, see if it works.  then start adding the joins/etc until you figure out what is wrong

Comment: That is a very good idea. I haven't thought about that. I will let you know what happens

Comment: I'm even more confused than before. I changed the join method so that it was matching the month from the date and it still returns no results. The only time I could get it to work was when I took out the join statement completely. What would explain why a join statement would used to work when the dataset was local and now doesn't when the dataset is changed to a class library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet that your date field is returning a DATETIME from the database and you are wanting all records with the same date.

```
join d in dailyAmexTable.AsEnumerable() on c.Date equals d.Date
```

The line above will return only transactions with the same HH:MM:SS:MS.

Comment: The code hasn't changed and the example of a date is 2000-04-25. The problem only started after I created a class library for the dataset and started referencing this instead. The tables are still getting filled with the same info as before and the code hasn't changed at all

Comment: What can I do to fix this problem?